# Joinable group video chat rooms using Quickblox

Tags: ios, swift, quickblox, videochat

I am currently developing an iOS application which requires users to join video chat rooms, very similar to how [Houseparty](https://houseparty.com) and [Airtime](https://www.airtime.com) works. However, I don't know where to start, nor what third party service I should use in order to incorporate this in my app. From what I can find online, Quickblox seem to be one of the best, but on the other hand, it seems to only offer "video calls", meaning that in order to start a group video chat, you have to call users, in contrast to how for example Houseparty works where you can join a room without accepting a call. [This issue](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/issues/856) even seems to state that it is not even possible to do this at all. My question is therefore, is it possible to use Quickblox in order to develop an application that allows users to have video group chats, without ever calling someone and instead allow them to join the video group chat sporadically? If not, which third party service makes this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular calls in quick blox are implemented as a peer to peer calls. The feature you need is conference call . Quick blox have custom enterprise solution with the usage of server-side, it provide call with 10 to 15 users but in the enterprise tier . Check Out link below.

[Quick blox](https://quickblox.com/developers/EnterpriseFeatures#Conference_video_calls)

Comment: QB really is amazing

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is it possible to have conference calls with less than 10 users without using the enterprise plan? Or are conference calls in general only available on the enterprise plan?

Comment: i'm afraid this is not available . as much as i know . You can read [Here](https://quickblox.com/developers/EnterpriseFeatures#Conference_video_calls)